# an application of the second Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability

Suppose that {$Z_k$} are independent and identically distributed random variables such that $P(Z_1=z)<1$ for any $z\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $P(Z_k\ converges\ for \ k\rightarrow\infty)=0$.

The hint is useing the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I don't know how to use it. The most difficult thing for me is how to describe the convergence by a sequence of  sets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An i.i.d sequence $(Z_n)$ can converge with probability $1$ only when $Z_1$ is a constant.  Note that by Kolomogorov 0-1 law $P (Z_n converges)$ is $0$ or $1$. So if it is not zero then $Z_n$ converges a.s. and $Z_1=c$ a.s. for some $c$. But this contradicts the hypothesis.

[Suppose $Z_n$ converges a.s.. Then $Z=lim Z_n$ is measurable w.r.t. the tail sigma algebra and hence it is a.s.  constant. But $Z_n$ and $Z$ have the same distribution  (by convergence in distribution) so $Z_1$ is a.s. constant].

Alternate proof: let $X_n=Z_{2n}-Z_{2n-1}$. Then $(X_n)$ is also i.i.d.. Consider $\sum_n P(|X_n| >\epsilon)$. This is $\infty$ provided $P(|X_1| >\epsilon) \neq 0$. By Borel -Cantelli Lemma this implies that $|X_n| >\epsilon i.o.$ with probability $1$. It is clear that $Z_n$ cannot converge if $|X_n| >\epsilon i.o.$.  It remains to see that $P(|X_1| >\epsilon) \neq 0$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Assume  the contrary: $P(|X_1| >\epsilon) = 0$ for every $\epsilon >0$. Then $Z_1=Z_2$ almost surely. Since $Z_2$ is independent of $Z_1$ it follows that $Z_1$ is independent of  itself, Hence a constant $z$ a.s.. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @I.D.D I have now added a proof relying only on the second part of Borel - Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: Thank you so much for the two excellent proofs!!! It did broaden my horizon.